# Repeating graphics withing view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics

In Unity2D, I have made a script to repeat the background sprite just before the camera can see the end.

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent (typeof(SpriteRenderer))]

public class Tiling : MonoBehaviour {

    public int offsetX = 2;         // the offset so that we don't get any weird errors

    // these are used for checking if we need to instantiate stuff
    public bool hasARightBuddy = false;
    public bool hasALeftBuddy = false;

    public bool reverseScale = false;   // used if the object is not tilable

    private float spriteWidth = 0f;     // the width of our element
    private Camera cam;
    private Transform myTransform;
    private float localSc;

    void Awake () {
        cam = Camera.main;
        myTransform = transform;
        localSc = transform.localScale.x;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        SpriteRenderer sRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        spriteWidth = sRenderer.sprite.bounds.size.x * transform.localScale.x;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // does it still need buddies? If not do nothing
        if (hasALeftBuddy == false || hasARightBuddy == false) {
            // calculate the cameras extend (half the width) of what the camera can see in world coordinates
            float camHorizontalExtend = cam.orthographicSize * Screen.width/Screen.height;

            // calculate the x position where the camera can see the edge of the sprite (element)
            float edgeVisiblePositionRight = (myTransform.position.x + spriteWidth/2) - camHorizontalExtend;
            float edgeVisiblePositionLeft = (myTransform.position.x - spriteWidth/2) + camHorizontalExtend;

            // checking if we can see the edge of the element and then calling MakeNewBuddy if we can
            if (cam.transform.position.x >= edgeVisiblePositionRight - offsetX && hasARightBuddy == false)
            {
                MakeNewBuddy (1);
                hasARightBuddy = true;
            }
            else if (cam.transform.position.x <= edgeVisiblePositionLeft + offsetX && hasALeftBuddy == false)
            {
                MakeNewBuddy (-1);
                hasALeftBuddy = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // a function that creates a buddy on the side required
    void MakeNewBuddy (int rightOrLeft) {
        // calculating the new position for our new buddy
        Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3 (myTransform.position.x + spriteWidth * rightOrLeft, myTransform.position.y, myTransform.position.z);
        // instantating our new body and storing him in a variable
        Transform newBuddy = Instantiate (myTransform, newPosition, myTransform.rotation) as Transform;

        newBuddy.parent = myTransform.parent;

        // if not tilable let's reverse the x size on our object to get rid of missmatches
        if (reverseScale == true) {
            newBuddy.localScale = new Vector3 (localSc*-1 , 1, 1);
        }



        if (rightOrLeft == 1) { //if this function was called to make a right buddy (1)
            newBuddy.GetComponent<Tiling>().hasALeftBuddy = true;
        }
        else { //else we just made a left buddy, so it has a right copy
            newBuddy.GetComponent<Tiling>().hasARightBuddy = true;
        }
    }
```

Now, the script is attached to the background sprite and it works fine.
You'll see that there's a `bool` reverseScale to reverse the image.
This is because if the image is not repeatable, (the end and the start to not match on a pixel level) we can mirror it by reverting (* -1) the `x` scale.

The strange thing is, if I launch this with reverseScale disabled, eveything works as I said. **If I enable reverseScale**, it becomes a mess. Infinite loop of overlapping, badly scaled sprites, crashing the game.

What am I missing? Worst case (but still shouldn't happen), that code snippet should make an image that doesn't match, why is it breaking the program?

**EDIT:**

I found a solution thanks to Enfyve answer. I was flipping the scale of the whole graphic component instead oa  single one for come reason. the flipX field should be used instead. Also, only one every two tiles has to be flipped, to avoid missmatches.

Comment: The class doesn't necessarily have any runaway loops, so it must be somewhere else that is causing the problem. Also, you're getting the `Tiling` component of `newBuddy`, but did you add the component in the first place? (I don't see it here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpriteRenderer already contains a property to draw a sprite flipped, use `flipX` instead.